# Crash in OnActivityResult called on return from authenticating with ADAL

Tags: android, xamarin, adal

I had ADAL working well for authentication on my Xamarin Android app. Recently things stopped working. Now I even get a crash with the NativeClient-MultiTarget-DotNet sample app. Using Xamarin Android 5.1.1.0 and Android v5.1 (lollipop) on both nexus 5 and galaxy note 3.

After I authenticate via the web interface, and the 2-factor auth, etc. there is an apparent crash trying to call my OnActivityResult:

```
0x0 in DirSearchClient_Android.MainActivity.OnActivityResult at d:\src\oss\ADD-NativeClient-sample\DirSearchClient-Android\MainActivity.cs:21,-1 C#
0x18 in Android.App.Activity.n_OnActivityResult_IILandroid_content_Intent_ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/1780/3518c4ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2144,4 C#
0x23 in object.4f36edd6-202e-4f86-b299-3f790f046593 C#
```

This occurs using both 3.1.203031538 and 3.3.205061641 of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory . Thoughts?

Comment: This could be a manifestation of the decimal comparison bug in Mono: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29570

Comment: Upgrade to the alpha or beta channels (Xamarin.Android v5.1.1 or v5.1.2) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: good idea, but no joy.

Comment: I tried the same sample application on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.4 and it worked. No crash.